# In unix, are dot and double dot path or directory?

Tags: linux, unix, directory, path, console

That is, do they take up storage space? Is dot a copy of the current directory? Could I say that dot and double dot are subdirectories of the current directory?

Comment: They are "pointers" --  One points to the current director IE `cd ./` and the other points to the parent directory IE `cd ../`  And -- If you do a `ls -lah` you will see exactly how little space these pointer take up

Comment: In addition it helps to think of them as "hard links" although they don't count against the link-count since you technically cannot hard link a directory.

Comment: When you do `readdir` the first two values returned are `.` and `..` so they take up two directory entries.

Comment: @nullptr As I stated .. They **are not** directories ..  They are *links to* directories.   More explanation and info can be found --> http://teaching.idallen.com/dat2330/04f/notes/links_and_inodes.html

Comment: From the userspace point of view, `/usr`, `/usr/.` and `/usr/bin/..` are directories in exactly the same way. Whether that way is "none of them are directories, they're just links" or "all of them are directories" depends on how pedantic you want to me.

Comment: Yes, but regardless the number of links they all point to one directory.

Comment: @nullptr  It's never a copy of the directory, no matter how you define things. `.` and `..` were traditionally implemented as independent copies of *a pointer* to the same abstract directory object, but they have never and would never duplicate the actual directory object or any file data of any files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A directory is logically a table used to map names to filesystem objects such as files or directories.  Files can have multiple names and can be in multiple directories.  The extra directory entries are links to the same file; the file itself is not duplicated.  The same is true for directories.  The '.' entry is a name which always maps to the directory that it is in.  '..' maps to the parent, but in the case of the root directory it maps to itself.